# How to add custom fields to Meteor.users collection?

Tags: meteor, user-accounts, meteor-accounts, meteor-useraccounts

Sorry for my english. I use the package useraccounts:bootstrap for login, registration and so on. How can I add arbitrary data to Meteor.users collection after registration. For example, I want, that users after registration had a field 'status' with a value of 'false' or the field 'time' with time of registration. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the user needs to supply the data, you will need to [customize the UI](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md#form-fields-configuration) and add the desired fields.

On the server, you can attach an `onCreateUser()` callback to set the data when a new user is created.

```js
import _ from 'lodash';

Accounts.onCreateUser((options, user) => {
  // add your extra fields here; don't forget to validate the options, if needed
  _.extend(user, {
    status: false,
    createdAt: new Date()
  });

  return user;
});
```

the `options` argument contains the data from the client side.

Answer (score 2):

*useraccounts:bootstrap* provides you a way to customize your registration panel templates by adding visible, explicit and editable fields into the registration form, as explained in useraccounts/core's GitHub documentation(look for **AccountTemplates.addFields** method).

However, *useraccounts:bootstrap* is dependent on *accounts-password*, so you can use its **Accounts.createUser** method, simply by passing additional fields in the object passed into **Accounts.createUser** method. Your createUser method would be like:

```
Accounts.createUser({
   username:'newuser',
    password:'pass1234',
    profile:{ //no sensitive data here, this can be modified by the user
          },
    registrationTime: new Date, //date & time of registration
    status: false

    });
```

This problem was discussed on Meteor forums:[forums.meteor.com](https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-to-add-new-field-on-meteor-users/1065/5).

A more elegant way of solving your problem is calling a server-side function **Accounts.onCreateUser** every time a user account is created. This function would assign the registrationTime and status to the newly created account. Check this in Meteor's docs: Accounts.onCreateUser [docs.meteor.com](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser)

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I'm doing it; matches the meteor docs style and doesn't require lodash:

```
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';

Accounts.onCreateUser((options, user) => {
  const userToCreate = Object.assign({
    status: false,
    createdAt: new Date(),
  }, user);

  if (options.profile) userToCreate.profile = options.profile;

  return userToCreate;
});
```